# Navigation Bar setting an Active Tab when user on page?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I implemented this Navigation Bar, quite complex coding for me, but i did it and styled it and took care of everything. I just didn't manage to set an Active state on tabs when a user lands on that tab's page. For example, if i have a "Funny" tab, and the user clicks on it, i want it to change color/background while the user is on that page...

I tried solving this myself before bothering anybody with it, but i failed to get it done.

Here are my codes:

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul class="level1">

    **<li class="level1-li"><a class="level1-a" href="#url">Home</a></li>**

    **<li class="level1-li"><a class="level1-a fly" href="#url">Contact Us<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->**

<!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <ul class="level2">
  <li><a href="#url">Email</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Telephone</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Online Form</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Snail Mail Address</a></li>
</ul>
  <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>

    **<li class="level1-li"><a class="level1-a fly" href="#url">Resort<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->**
<!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <ul class="level2">
    <li><a href="#url">Ski Hire Facilities</a></li>
    <li><a class="fly" href="#url">Main Ski Slopes<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
   <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <ul class="level3">
  <li><a href="#url">Beginners Slopes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Intermediate Slopes</a></li>
    <li><a class="fly" href="#url">Advanced Skill Levels<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
   <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <ul class="level4">
  <li><a href="#url">Local</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Nearby</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">With instructor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Snow boarding</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
    <li><a href="#url">Expert</a></li>
    </ul>
  <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
    <li><a href="#url">Night Life</a></li>
    <li><a class="fly" href="#url">Restaurants<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <ul class="level3">
    <li><a href="#url">Snow Hotel</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">The Snowman</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Ice Cavern</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Ski Inn</a></li>
    </ul>
  <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
    <li><a class="fly" href="#url">Car Hire<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
     <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <ul class="level3">
    <li><a href="#url">From Airport</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">In Resort</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Multiple Resorts</a></li>
    </ul>
  <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
  </ul>
  <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>

    **<li class="level1-li"><a class="level1-a fly" href="#url">Surrounding Area<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->**
<!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <ul class="level2">
  <li><a href="#url">Where to go</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">What to do</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Places of interest</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">National parks &amp; Museums</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>

    **<li class="level1-li left"><a class="level1-a fly" href="#url">Information<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->**
<!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <ul class="level2">
  <li><a href="#url">Money Exchange</a></li>
  <li><a class="fly" href="#url">Resort Essential Information<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
   <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <ul class="level3">
  <li><a href="#url">Lift Passes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Insurance</a></li>
  <li><a class="fly" href="#url">Gear Rental<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
   <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <ul class="level4">
  <li><a href="#url">Boots</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Skis</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Ski Wear</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Goggles</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Ski Schools</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Snow Report</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
  <li><a class="fly" href="#url">Language<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
   <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <ul class="level3">
  <li><a href="#url">Austrian</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">German</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">French</a></li>
  <li><a href="#url">English</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
  <li><a href="#url">Short Breaks</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>

    **<li class="level1-li"><a class="level1-a" href="#url">Privacy</a></li>**

    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* ================================================================
  This copyright notice must be kept untouched in the stylesheet at all times. The original version of this stylesheet and the associated (x)html is available at http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/anywidth2.html
  Copyright (c) 2005-2009 Stu Nicholls. All rights reserved. This stylesheet and the associated (x)html may be modified in any way to fit your requirements.
  =================================================================== */
  #menu {width:740px; background: #3aa3d3; height:25px; text-align:center; position:relative; z-index:20;}
  #menu ul {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;}
  #menu ul {display:inline-block;}
  #menu li {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
  #menu li {clear:both;float:none;}
  #menu ul ul {position:absolute; left:-9999px;}
  #menu ul.level1 {margin:0 auto;}
  #menu ul.level1 li.level1-li {float:left; display:block; position:relative;clear:none;}
  #menu ul.level1 {background:#3aa3d3;}
  #menu ul.level2 {background:#ae4621;}
  #menu ul.level3 {background:#c98b14;}
  #menu ul.level4 {background:#9f690e;}
  #menu b {position:absolute;} /* -- for IE6 non-flyout dropdowns to stop flickering - who knows why --*/
  #menu a {display:block; font:normal 11px verdana,arial,sans-serif; color:#fff; line-height:25px; text-decoration:none;padding:0 15px 0 15px;outline:none;}
  #menu ul.level1 li.level1-li a.level1-a {float:left;}
  #menu ul li:hover > ul {visibility:visible; left:0; top:25px;}
  #menu ul ul li:hover > ul {visibility:visible; left:100%; top:auto; margin-top:-25px;}
  #menu li.left:hover > ul {visibility:visible; left:auto; right:0; top:25px;}
  #menu li.left ul li:hover > ul {visibility:visible; left:auto; right:100%; top:auto; margin-top:-25px;}
  #menu a:hover ul {left:0; top:23px;}
  #menu li.left a:hover ul {left:auto; right:-1px; top:23px;}
  #menu li.left ul a {text-align:right; padding:0 15px 0 15px;}
  #menu a:hover a:hover ul,
  #menu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul {left:100%; visibility:visible;}
  #menu li.left a:hover a:hover ul,
  #menu li.left a:hover a:hover a:hover ul {left:auto; right:0; visibility:visible;}
  #menu a:hover ul ul,
  #menu a:hover a:hover ul ul {left:-9999px;}
  #menu li.left a:hover ul ul,
  #menu li.left a:hover a:hover ul ul {left:-9999px;}
  #menu li a.fly {font-variant: small-caps;}
  #menu li.left ul a.fly {font-variant: small-caps;}
  #menu li a:hover,
  #menu li a.fly:hover {background-color:#555555;}
  #menu li:hover > a,
  #menu ul li:hover > a.fly {background-color:#555555;}
  #menu table {position:absolute; height:0; width:0; left:0; border-collapse:collapse; margin-top:-4px;}
  #menu table table {position:absolute; left:99%; height:0; width:0; border-collapse:collapse; margin-top:-29px;}
  #menu li.left table {position:absolute; height:0; width:0; left:auto; right:0; border-collapse:collapse; margin-top:-4px;}
  #menu li.left table table {position:absolute; left:auto; right:100%; height:0; width:0; border-collapse:collapse; margin-top:-29px;}
  #menu ul, .tabs-outer {overflow:visible;}
  #menu li a {border: none;}
  .main-outer {z-index:10;}/*for IE*/
  .tabs-outer {z-index:11;}/*for IE*/
```

Hope somebody can help. :)

Comment: You'd better put your code on a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Well, im gonna sound stupid, there's no way around it... Why would i do that, i mean, how's that gonna help? :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a separate css class `a.active` and style it with necessary color for background and text. Add the active class to the html `a` tag where ever needed. For example when in home page add `active` class as shown below

```
<li class="level1-li"><a class="level1-a active" href="#url">Home</a></li>

a.active { background-color: green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, in every page you create you need to define a specific `id`. like

```
<body id="home">
//your all code
</body>
```

and then you can just look in that page which contains that id using `Javascript`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#home').css({'background-color':'red', 'color':'#000'});

});
```

**Updated**

You need to insert the `JQuery` and the `js` code before the

```
<body>
//all your code



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#home').css({'background-color':'red', 'color':'#000'});

    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok, that sounds simple... But for the javascript, i am working on a blogger blog, where should i insert that javascript code? I mean, should it be somewhere within the CSS, or the HTML, or in the <head> of the blog, or in the <body> part???

Comment: You need to include the jquery library too and you can insert this before `</body>`

Comment: Oh, jquery... Thanks for trying to help, but i already have 2-4 jquery's in my blog's HTML... And everything works good. However, whenever a new jquery is inserted it just f***s shit up and messes things up and then i gotta look for a solution... I don't want to use jquery for anything which isn't a necessity... Plus i wouldn't know which jquery to use, and also from what i know (i could be wrong) javascript slows down a site's loading time etc, and i don't want that... I know it can be done purely with CSS, i just don't know how to do it :p

Comment: if jquery is already there then you just need to add the code.